# strftime from datetime not printing correct value for certain directives

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1)
print(x.strftime("%V"))
```

This simply does not work in my coding environment. Neither does a few other directives besides V. It prints %V instead of 22. This code works in w3schools though.
Additionally, to find week number I tried `isocalendar()`.

```
 File VFS.datetime.py, line 1123, in isocalendar
  return _IsoCalendarDate(year,week+1,day+1)
 File VFS.datetime.py, line 1217, in __new__
  return super().__new__(cls,(year,week,weekday))
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

This is the error I get from `isocalendar()` so I gave up on that.

Comment: I tried your first snippet and it printed `22`.

Comment: Yea for whatever reason that and other directives specifically don't work in my environment. But %B works fine.

Comment: `x.isocalendar()` also works fine. Sounds like a problem with your Python installation.

Comment: from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior): "*These may not be available on all platforms when used with the strftime()*"